# What is the equivalent in PHP for Python's pass statement?

Tags: php, python, language-comparisons

Do you know any PHP statement that works like Python's `pass` statement?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just leave the bracket's empty...

Python has the pass word because they don't use brackets to define the body part of classes, function, and other statement. PHP doesn't have this dilemma , and therefore doesn't need something to say that a body statement is empty.

Comment: i need it to use in ternary operator. `(condition?something:pass)`;
`condition?something:` ends with error

Comment: @Jan Tojnar: Use an empty string `''`. If you use the ternary operator, you mostly assign a value to a variable. This will assign `false` then (empty string is false). If you do not use it for variable assignment, it what use a plain `if` statement. Much easier to understand then.

Comment: Can't you just use `result = condition ? something : result`?

Answer (score 27):

It isn't needed in PHP. The Python code:

```
if x == y:
    pass
```

Can be written in PHP by just leaving the brackets empty

```
if ( x == y ){
}
```

The same applies to other PHP constructs requiring brackets such as classes or functions.

Comment: And better yet, add a comment in those empty brackets so that you can remember what you were trying to do there..

Answer (score 9):

Can't you just use a semicolon?

```
if ( $x == $y )
  ;
```

Answer (score 3):

When needed for readability you could use

```
null;
```

Answer (score 1):

*NULL* is the alternative for *pass* in python

```
$a == $b? $b = 10 : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax checkers and linters are becoming more and more good at signaling not useful block of codes, also when this is a voluntary action of the developer.

A `native do_nothing()` function would be very nice and readable sometimes.

To avoid stressing alerts from syntax checkers, I use:

```
echo(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "goto" is not the same but it can help.

For more infos:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

if($a == 1){
    echo "-> A == 1 Good!\n";
    if($b == 2){
        echo "-> Now we need to jump to thisline \n";
      goto thisline;
    };
}else{
    thisline: 
    echo "\n--->Nice we actually jumbed!<---";
}
?>
```