# Is there anything similar to the pass keyword from python in php

Tags: php

If I want to ignore something in python I usually just put pass

example

```
if a > b:
   pass
```

how do i do something similar in php?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? What does `pass` do?

Comment: @Nico Hasse it makes it so that it doesn't execute anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent in PHP for Python's pass statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852784/what-is-the-equivalent-in-php-for-pythons-pass-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for something similar.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_pass.asp states:

> When the pass statement is executed, nothing happens, but you avoid
> getting an error when empty code is not allowed. Empty code is not
> allowed in loops, function definitions, class definitions, or in if
> statements.

But in PHP emtpty code is allowed.